# ASP RequiredField Validator on disabled Text Box validation failure

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a problem with asp.net required field validator. In my situation I have a text box that depends on a DropDownList: if a value is selected the TextBox is active, otherwise it is disabled and putted inside the 0 value.

What I suppose the validator to do is to check if the textbox is empty and:

- If the textbox is disabled the value is 0 => Validation pass
- If the textbox is enabled the value depends on suser => Validation depending on the user input

What I found is if the textbox is disabled and has a value inside, the validator block the postback and shows the message even if in the textbox there is the 0 value! (I tried also with NA or something like that)

Here is my code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_CIGUnico" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="txt_CIGUnico_Validator" ControlToValidate="txt_CIGUnico" Display="Dynamic" InitialValue="" ErrorMessage="Inserisci un valore per il CIG"/>
```

And the jQuery on the dropdown do something like:

```
if ($("[name*='tipoCIG']").attr('value') == "Singolo") {
    $("[name*='txt_CIGUnico']").removeAttr("disabled");
}
else {
    $("[name*='txt_CIGUnico']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("[name*='txt_CIGUnico']").val("0");
}
```

Any suggestion?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Javascript to enable/disable the RFV as needed.

```
ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%=txt_CIGUnico_Validator.ClientID%>'), false);
```

The second argument sets the validator to enabled (true) or disabled (false).